# How to prevent git doing a fast-forward when rebasing a branch that's been merged, then reverted

Tags: git

I have a branch called feature which branches off main at commit F, with two commits, A and B.

This was merged with a merge commit, M, and then the merged was reverted with commit R.

I now want to rebase branch feature so it's on the tip of main, with its commits A and B again, (so I can carry on working on it and fix the problem that caused the revert to be needed).

However, when I do `git rebase main`, git just fast-forwards me to the tip of main, presumably because it sees that A and B are already on main.

How do I force this?

I've tried `git rebase --onto main SHA_FOR_F --no-ff` but that does the same thing.

Here's the situation:

```
R - main
|
M
|\
| B - feature
| |
| A
|/
F
|
```

and I'd like:

```
B - feature
|
A
|
R - main
|
M
|\
| B
| |
| A
|/
F
|
```

I know I could just cherry-pick A and B individually, but is there a way of doing this in one go?

Comment: It's not that Git is doing a "fast-forward" with these, it's that rebase itself is detecting patch-equivalent commits in the upstream, and removing the commits from the list of commits to be copied.

Comment: Indeed, but I think the output on the terminal mentions fast-forward.

Comment: There is a kind of fast-forward option with merging, but that's to re-use existing commits. That is, suppose you `git rebase --onto X` while on branch B with commits Y and Z, and suppose that the actual topology is `...--X--Y--Z`. Then commits Y and Z already exist as two commits immediately following X, so `git rebase` by default re-uses them. Adding `-f` or `--no-ff` (either one) tells rebase to copy Y and Z anyway. Rebase doesn't say anything about this at the time it does it, though.

Answer (score 4):

(if you only have 2 commits, cherry-picking by hand is obviously a very viable option)

You can also pass a range to `git cherry-pick` :

```
git cherry-pick F..B
```

This will skip the "detect if a commit is already part of target branch" algorithm which `git rebase` does.

---

*[edit]*

actually, `git rebase` also has an option to skip this check : [`--reapply-cherry-picks`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---reapply-cherry-picks) (added in v2.27, Q2 2020)

```
git rebase --reapply-cherry-picks --onto master F B
```

the advantage being you can also add `--interactive`, and edit yourself what should and shouldn't be kept.

Comment: Thanks! (It's more than 2 commits; I was simplifying.)

Comment: Note that `--reapply-cherry-picks` was new in Git 2.27.